# exporting multiple tables on a mysql database

Tags: mysql, csv, export, command-line-interface

mysql v5.5

When I use below statements after 'use db', it just won't start copying to output file. It just show prompt when I pressed Enter

```
mysql> SELECT id,
    -> name,
    -> purchases,
    -> sales
    -> INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/shop.csv'
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n
    '>
```

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. This is what I used,

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, .... , col_n 
FROM table_name 
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/your/csv/csv_name.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Hope this will help.

FYI:You can use more tables and your syntax should be change according to that.

```
SELECT table_1.col_1, table_1.col_2, .... , table_1.col_n, table_2,col_1, ... , table_m,col_n
FROM table_1,table_2,...,table_n
```

and rest as it is. I f you want to reduce data you can use where clauses too.

Comment: I see, so I need to specify columns of a table and do that for every table of a database instead of specifying every table that I want since every tables have different columns.

Comment: True, you can do that way. Also if you are using phpmyadmin you can export the file with different requirements.